# duvida com if else em java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if, else

Estou usando AngularJs e tenho esse método

```
$scope.login = function (email, usuario, senha) {
    $http.post("/Login/login", { email: email, usuario: usuario, senha: senha })
    .success(function (data) {
        debugger;

        if (data == "Empresa nao encontrada.") {
            UIkit.modal.alert(data, { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
            return;
        }
        else if (data == "Usuário ou Senha inválidos.") {
            UIkit.modal.alert(data, { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
            return;
        }
        else {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('acessos', JSON.stringify(data));//coloca os acessos em uma sessão.storage
            window.location.href = '#/';
        }
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        alert("Erro");
    });
};
```

O *BackEnd* está retornando "Empresa não encontrada." isso pode ser visto na imagem a seguir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o código do `if (data == "Empresa nao encontrada.") {...}` não é executado, é executado apenas o código do `else`, porque?

Comment: Não sei muito bem , sou iniciante , mas acredito que é porque o `data` que é você esta pegando em `.success(function (data)` , é igual ao objeto que você esteja passando no `$http.post` , então ele não pode ser essa string `"Empresa nao encontrada"`

Answer (score 2):

O código

```
.success(function (data) {
    //...
}
```

Retorna o seguinte objeto:

> **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>
> **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>
> **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

[Fonte](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

---

Portanto, para que seu código funcione, você deve fazer referência ao `data` que é onde está a resposta propriamente dita, ficando assim:

```
if (data.data == "Empresa nao encontrada.") {
    UIkit.modal.alert(data, { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
    return;
} else if (data.data == "Usuário ou Senha inválidos.") {
    UIkit.modal.alert(data, { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
    return;
}
```

Comment: data.data nao funcionou, data.data da erro de undefined. Pra resolver, mudei o meu retorno do back, agora retorna 0 ou 1, deu certo, mas a comparação de string nao funcionou, estranho...